# how to check whether old password entered is present or not in db

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I m having a login page where user enters id and password.To reset the password i have to check whether the entered password is present or not whether it matches with the id i have entered.How to validate it.I m unable to validate it. If user enters any password it displays the record is updated. How to validate it. Here is the code

login.php

```
<label type="text" name="id" maxlength="50" size="20">ID</label><br />
<input type="text" name="id" placeholder="ID" class="input" size="20"/><br /></div>
<div class="formItem">

 <label type="text" name="uid" maxlength="50" size="20">Password</label><br />
<input type="password" name="uid" placeholder="ID" class="input" size="20"/><br /></div>




<span class="field">(* Required field)</span><br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="login1" value="LOGIN" class="button"><br /><br /><br /><br />
</form>

</div>




</body>

</html>

<?php
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$hostname = "localhost"; 
$db = "abc";

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
mysql_select_db($db,$dbhandle) or die('cannot select db');





if(isset($_POST['login1']))
{
$id= $_POST['id'];
$uid= $_POST['uid'];

$query= "select * from resume where id='$id'
AND uid='$uid'";
$run= mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($run)>0){
echo "<script>window.open('resetp.php','_self')</script>";
}
else {

    echo "<script>alert('Login details are incorrect!')</script>";
    }
}
?>
```

resetp.php

```
 <label type="text" name="uid" maxlength="50" size="20">Old Password</label><br />
<input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="id" class="input" size="20"/><br /></div>    


<div class="formItem">

 <label type="text" name="uid" maxlength="50" size="20">New Password</label><br />
<input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="pass" class="input" size="20"/><br /></div>
<div class="formItem">
 <label type="text" name="cpas" maxlength="50" size="20">Confirm Password</label><br />
<input type="password" name="cpas" placeholder="" class="input" size="20"/><br /></div>


<div class="formItem">
<input type="submit" name="login1" value="RESET" class="formButton"><br /><br /><br /><br /></div>
</form>
<?php
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$hostname = "localhost"; 
$db = "resume1";

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
mysql_select_db($db,$dbhandle) or die('cannot select db');
if(isset($_POST['login1']))
{
$pass= $_POST['pass'];
$uid= $_POST['uid'];


$cpas=$_POST['cpas'];

$query = "Update `resume` SET uid='".$_POST['pass']."' where uid='".$_POST['uid']."'";
$run = mysql_query($query);
if($query)
{
    echo "<script>alert('Record updated')</script>";
}
else
{
    echo "<script>alert('no')</script>";


}
}

?>
```

How can i validated it

Comment: If fails then it's invalid.

Comment: `Update resume SET uid='".$_POST['pass']."' where uid='".$_POST['uid']."'` Here you set `uid` to the password which is probably wrong (and it probably fails since you can't update columns you use in your where clause). Also, you have quite a few security issues. First, you do not escape user input which you should always do. Second, you are storing plain passwords in the database. You should at least use simple hash like `md5()` to store the passwords (but there are even better ways, try to read about salting passwords).

Comment: ya..I want to validate old password is of same id and old password is whether the same as enterd in form.

Comment: Next thing, you use `if($query)` instead of `if($run)`. The first will always be true since the query is a non-null string.

Comment: Where are you checking the password? Also SQL injection galore.

Answer (score 1):

```html
Try this:

This line

<label type="text" name="uid" maxlength="50" size="20">New Password</label><br />

should be 

<label type="text" name="pass" maxlength="50" size="20">New Password</label><br />
```

Comment: old password name is uid and new password is pass

Comment: You also need to send id along with old password and new password. Because two or more users may have same password.

So modify your query 
$query = "Update `resume` SET uid='".$_POST['pass']."' where id='".$_POST['id']."' AND uid='".$_POST['uid']."'";

Answer (score 0):

I guess couldn't understand your requirement.

Why don't you validate like you are doing in login.php

```
 $query= "select * from resume where id='$id'
 AND uid='$uid'";
 $run= mysql_query($query);.................
```

Comment: Or put a extra Where condition -- where password = '".$_POST['pass']."'

Answer (score 0):

the `PHP` script should be at the beginning, not at the end of the code. Begin with the `<?php .... ?>` and then follow the `<HTML> ... </HTML>` otherwise the result is returned even before the script is processed.

There are a lot of security issues with your code. You can try this.

```
<?php
   require 'db.php';

   $username = isset($_POST['username']) ? htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['username']), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') : '';
    $password = isset($_POST['password']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['password'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') : '';

   $error = array();
   $error_found = 0;

   if(isset($_POST['submit']) && ($_POST['submit'] == 'Reset'))
    {
        //check for errors.
        //check if username field is empty.
        if(empty($username))
         {
             $error[] = 'Please provide your user-name.';
         }
         //check if password field is empty.
         if(empty($password))
         {
             $error[] = 'Please provide a password.';
         }
         //if errors exist, put errors found as true.
         if(!empty($error))
         {
             $error_found = 1;
         }
         //else no errors are found.
         else
        {
            //proceed to reset.
            //connecting to database.
            $db = mysql_connect(MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD) or die('Unable to connect, check your connection parameters. ');
            mysql_select_db(MYSQL_DB, $db) or die('Could not select database, check availability. ' . mysql_error($db));

            //querying the database. Checking if user-name password combination exists.
            $query = 'SELECT username FROM resume WHERE username = "' . mysql_real_escape_string($username, $db) . 
                        '" AND password = PASSWORD("' . mysql_real_escape_string($password, $db) . '")';

            $result = mysql_query($query, $db) or die(mysql_error($db));

            //checking if result is true.
            if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
            {
                //the result is true and so you can now reset your password.
            }
            else
            {
                $error[] = 'The username password combination you provided does not exist.';
                $error_found = 1;
            }
        }
    }
  //HTML
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>
     <head><title> ... </title></head>
     <body>
          <!--Your html code here -->
          <?php
             //if errors are found, then errors are shown here.
             if($error_found == 1)
             {
                echo '<fieldset><center>';
                echo '<ul>';
                foreach($error as $e)
                {
                    echo '<li>' . $e . '</li>';
                }
                echo '</ul>';
                echo '</center></fieldset>';
            }
        ?>
        <form action="nameOfThisScript.php" method="POST">
        Username:<input id="username" type="text" name="username" required />
        Password:<input id="password" type="password" name="password" required />
        <button id="Reset" type="submit" name="submit" value="Reset">Reset</button>
        </form>
      </body>
    </html>
```

create a script named `db.php`  in the same folder as this script and put the code

```
<?php
define('MYSQL_HOST', 'localhost');
define('MYSQL_USER', 'root');
define('MYSQL_PASSWORD', '');
define('MYSQL_DB', 'resume1');
 ?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: please give me in details..As i didnt understand how to check old password is in the db or not whether it is so same username.i want to reset the password to

Comment: It is simple. First you have to create a form in html so that the data you are sending to the server is sent via  POST or GET. That is defined in the `method="POST"` in the form tag. the `required` in the `input` tags let the user know that the fields cannot be left empty. This is a HTML5 feature. Once the data is sent to the server, run some security checks to ensure no harmful code is sent. Check the database with the given data (see the query part) and if it returns a result, then the username-password combo exist, thus change it, maybe by redirecting to a new page or something.

Comment: Also remember to put the `php` part in the beginning. If the `HTML` is  in the beginning, the server returns the page to the client even before the `php` script is run.

Comment: One more thing you must keep in mind is that you should not store password as direct text in your DB. Bad practice. Hash it. MySQL uses a good hashing  technique using the `PASSWORD()`. Look into the `$query` where I checked the password by first hashing it by `PASSWORD("yourPasswordHere")`. I have assumed you have stored the password already by hashing. If not, you can also directly check the password as text.

Comment: i cant understand without code how to check it whether it is there i sdb or not.As i m new to php.

Comment: Go through my code, I already checked it for you in my code. I put a comment `//the result is true and so you can now reset your password.` in the place where the returned result is true. Now you can put your code there to change it.